Convert Array to Pandas Dataframe Columns
I have a column "ym:s:goalsID" in my dataframe, how to convert this columnt to 4 separate columns?
Screenshot of Dataframe
Now it is:
ym:s:goalsID
[26783434,282511740,26783434,282511740]

I need:
ym:s:goalsID_1   ym:s:goalsID_2   ym:s:goalsID_3   ym:s:goalsID_4
26783434         282511740        26783434         282511740

I tried:
pd.DataFrame(df1["ym:s:goalsID"].str.split('<delim>', expand=True).values,
             columns=['ym:s:goalsID_1', 'ym:s:goalsID_2', 'ym:s:goalsID_3', 'ym:s:goalsID_4'])

and
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df1['ym:s:goalsID'].str.split().values.tolist())

lst = df1["ym:s:goalsID"]
df2 = pd.DataFrame([lst])
df2.columns =['col1','col2','col3', 'col4']
df2

But it doesnt work
